# How to rollback all committed transactions if any error encountered while reading csv file records using hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

**I have a CSV file which contains around 10Mb data which I use to populate my entire database. Suppose If I encountered an error while reading a record from CSV file  I need to abort all my committed transactions ?**

In my project, I have a threshold like if 5% of my records in CSV go wrong I will abort all committed transactions associated with that CSV file else if less than 5% I will only take out that record a keep in a separate file.

pl let me know how to abort all committed transactions(involves 15+ DAO classes) in hibernate.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a transaction is comitted it can't be reversed. Not in Hibernate, not in any database!

To keep your operations reversible you need to keep them in the same **single, not yet comitted** transaction and if any (by default runtime) exception arises it will automatically be rollbacked and all changes reversed.

You tagged your question as Spring, in Spring you can use @Transactional annotation over the method, and all changes in that method will be reversed in case of any transaction, including other methods called from that method.

more here https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring

also there is any example here https://javamondays.com/spring-transactions-explained/